# Script throwing recursion error after function call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that sends a form to a controller method, and I was trying to make it a POST request, but I get a "too much recursion" error. Here´s the code:

```js
var modalConfirm = function(callback) {
  $("#modal-btn-si").on("click", function() {
    callback(true);
    $("#modal-confirm").modal('hide');
  });
  $("#modal-btn-no").on("click", function() {
    callback(false);
    $("#modal-confirm").modal('hide');
  });
};

function confirmar(form, text) {
  $("#modal-confirm").modal('show');
  modalConfirm(function(confirm) {
    if (confirm) {
      $.post("NuevaOpcion", {
        data: $('#' + form)
      });
    }
  });
};
```

The line I modified is

```
$.post("NuevaOpcion",{ data: $('#' + form) });
```

After I added the `$.post()` I got:

```
too much recursion[Saber más] jquery-3.3.1.js:8423:24
```

I'm quite lost, don't know how I'm making such mistake. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Why all the code?
This should work

You need to serialize the form too

```js
var currentForm;
$("#modal-btn-si").on("click", function() {
  $.post("NuevaOpcion", {
    data: $('#' + currentForm).serialize()
  });
  $("#modal-confirm").modal('hide');
});
$("#modal-btn-no").on("click", function() {
  $("#modal-confirm").modal('hide');
});

function confirmar(form, text) {
  currentForm = form;
  $("#modal-confirm").modal('show');
};
```

If you only have one form, remove the global var and use the ID

```
data: $('#actualID').serialize()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm trying your code, changed `.serialize();` to `.serialize(),` because of compilation error. Now, your code looks fantastic and executes without error, but it doesn't hit the controller method, and neither the "no" button closes the dialog now. Thanks again.

Comment: By the way, I should add that this script is part of an unfinished project I received to learn C#, JS and jQuery. I can change whatever I want, so if there's anything that could be implemented in other (better) way, please tell. Thanks.

Comment: Nope, none at all. However, I modified my original script following your comments and it works. I'm posting an answer now. Thank you very much.